# how to post associative array in ionic 3

Tags: laravel, authentication, ionic-framework, oauth, ionic3

When i try to post a data in associative array to rest api using ionic.
Only empty data receive in server side.
Is this method is correct or suggest any other method

```
   public login(credentials) {

    let apiUrl = this.urlService.apiUrl  + 'oauth/access_token';
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers});

     var postcredn=new Array();

     postcredn['username'] = "karthik@abcde.in";
     postcredn['password'] = "05550";
     postcredn['grant_type'] = "password";
     postcredn['client_id'] = "Outfit1548669";
     postcredn['client_secret'] = "a10620c85033abd17716cda245";


    console.log('iii'+postcredn['username'] );

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.post(apiUrl, postcredn,  options)

           .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
             console.log('json'+ JSON.stringify(postcredn));

           }, (err) => {
             reject(err);
             console.log(apiUrl);
           });
     });
    }

}           console.log(apiUrl);
           });
     });
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please rewrite following code:

First you need to create `interface` like:

```
export interface Postdata{
   username: String;
   password:String;
   grant_type:String;
   client_id: String;
   client_secret: String;
}
```

Then import it and set its value:

```
var postcredn:Postdata;
postcredn={
  username:'karthik@abcde.in',
  password:'05550',
  grant_type:'password',
  client_id:'Outfit1548669',
  client_secret:'a10620c85033abd17716cda245'
}
```

Finally post it via post method:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(apiUrl, postcredn,  options)

       .subscribe(res => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
         console.log('json'+ JSON.stringify(postcredn));

       }, (err) => {
         reject(err);
         console.log(apiUrl);
       });
 });
```

[image: output]
[image: code]

Comment: While trying this code. it shows an "TypeError: "postcredn is undefined" " @Utpaul

Comment: https://codepen.io/Gokulanathan/pen/JzzGNE please see my code on this link.

Comment: After update also error remains same.please see in above link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190598/discussion-between-utpaul-and-karthik).

Comment: Please update code postcredn. I already check it my console.log gives me proper output

Answer (score 0):

Associative arrays in Javascript are technically Objects and can't be instantiated via `new Array()`. To create one you can use any of `new Object()` or `{}`. So from the code you posted, you will define it as `var postcredn=new Object();` or `var postcredn={};`

In your Laravel code, you can access it as you would an associative array in PHP.